# deleting some rows from csv file in an array on iOS Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, opencsv

I am new to iOS and I have a `tableview` that gets its data from a csv file. What I would like to do is not show some rows in the file. Here is what the file looks like

> 1,1,1,event Name
>   ,id,list order,last name,first name,group

I want to show just the `1,1,1,event Name` in the `tableview` and then load anything under that that starts with a `,` to be in a detail view. How would i do this?

Comment: It is better to use sqlite db, you can easily handle db, and you can easily insert csv values to db.